# Combine select queries into an update

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a table with crunched data so I don't have to do it on the fly. But I have to update the table quite often. The table is starting to get big(700 rows) and it takes quite sometimes to update the records.

I currently have a set of 9 queries to update the table and I'm sure there is a way to make it in one query but I don't know it:
Here are the queries I have so far:

```
UPDATE checkouts SET total_colors = i.count_result,  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_result FROM "checkouts" WHERE class != 'green' OR class is null) i WHERE i.id = checkouts.id
UPDATE checkouts SET sum_red = i.sum_result,  FROM (SELECT SUM("checkouts"."total_workers") AS sum_result FROM "checkouts" WHERE "checkouts"."class" = 'red') i WHERE i.id = checkouts.id
UPDATE checkouts SET sum_red = i.sum_result,  FROM (SELECT SUM("checkouts"."total_workers") AS sum_result FROM "checkouts" WHERE "checkouts"."class" = 'blue') i WHERE i.id = checkouts.id
UPDATE checkouts SET sum_red = i.sum_result,  FROM (SELECT SUM("checkouts"."total_workers") AS sum_result FROM "checkouts" WHERE "checkouts"."class" = 'yellow') i WHERE i.id = checkouts.id
UPDATE checkouts SET sum_red = i.sum_result,  FROM (SELECT SUM("checkouts"."total_workers") AS sum_result FROM "checkouts" WHERE "checkouts"."class" = 'black') i WHERE i.id = checkouts.id
UPDATE checkouts SET green_count = i.count_result,  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_result FROM "checkouts" WHERE "checkouts"."company_id" = 113432 AND class = 'green') i WHERE i.id = checkouts.id
UPDATE checkouts SET code = i.code,  FROM (SELECT code FROM greens where code is not null GROUP BY code ORDER BY COUNT(code) DESC LIMIT 1) i WHERE i.company_id = checkouts.company_id
UPDATE checkouts SET code = i.email,  FROM (SELECT email FROM greens where email is not null GROUP BY email ORDER BY COUNT(email) DESC LIMIT 1) i WHERE i.company_id = checkouts.company_id
UPDATE checkouts SET total_workers = i.sum_result,  FROM (SELECT SUM("checkouts"."total_workers") AS sum_result FROM checkouts) i WHERE i.id = checkouts.company_id
```

Comment: There is no reason to store the totals in each row.  You should just fetch the values when you are reading the table.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing summary values in the detailed records (unless you really know what you are doing).  One possibility is to do the calculations when you query the table:

```
SELECT c.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN class <> 'green' OR class is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id),
       SUM(CASE WHEN class = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as total_red,
       . . . 
FROM checkouts;
```

In fact, your data structure looks totally off.  If I had to guess, you have line-item detail in `checkouts` and you are trying to add `order-level` summaries in.  You should really have multiple tables for this purpose.  These would often be called `Orders` and `OrderLines`.